# Procedure Local Data in TASM

Tags: assembly, syntax, local, procedure, tasm

I'm using TASM 2.51 and I would like to ask for the syntax to declare data local to the procedure. I don't want local variables that are placed on the stack. The data should be placed in the data segment, but the label only visible to one procedure. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - it's been a long time since I've used Turbo Assembler, but wasn't it something like this?

```
MyProc proc
  local MyVar : byte
...

MyProc endp
```